# Bash: литература

Tags: книги, bash

Можете посоветовать литературу для изучения bash ?
Читал то что есть в сети, но получилась каша.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начните с классического [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), есть перевод - [Искусство программирования на языке сценариев командной оболочки](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/BOOKS/abs-guide/flat/abs-book.html).

Но думаю, это вопрос на руткод.

Answer (score 0):

Если не пугает английский, то есть еще Pro Bash Programming.